# How to overwrite a default message for a default validator?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validation-engine

One of the legacy applications where I work is using Inline Form Validation Engine 2.6.2 aka [jQuery Validation Engine](https://github.com/posabsolute/jQuery-Validation-Engine). I need to set a custom message for a default validator. Here is all I have tried without success it just does not work since the default message still showing up.

Here is the HTML:

```html
<input type="checkbox" name="agreement" value="1" id="agreement_0" class="validate[minCheckbox[1]]">
<input type="checkbox" name="agreement" value="1" id="agreement_1" class="validate[minCheckbox[1]]">
```

And the Javascript/jQuery:

```
// Use the data-errormessage-range-underflow attribute on the inputs
// Ex:
<input type="checkbox" name="agreement" value="1" id="agreement_0" class="validate[minCheckbox[1]]" data-errormessage-range-underflow="custom error msg">

// Use the default data-* attributes and the -range-underflow
// Ex:
<input  type="checkbox" 
        name="agreement" 
        value="1" 
        id="agreement_0" 
        class="validate[minCheckbox[1]]" 
        data-errormessage-range-underflow="custom error msg"
        data-errormessage-custom-error="custom error msg"
        data-errormessage="custom error msg"
>

// Initialize the object with a custom message
// Ex:
<input  type="checkbox" 
        name="agreement" 
        value="1" 
        id="agreement_0" 
        class="validate[minCheckbox[1]] someclass" 
        data-errormessage-range-underflow="custom error msg"
        data-errormessage-custom-error="custom error msg"
        data-errormessage="custom error msg"
>

$("#theform").validationEngine({'custom_error_messages' : {
        '.someclass': {
            'range-underflow': {
                'message': "custom error message"
            }
        }
    }
});

// Use the title attribute and add the custom message there
<input type="checkbox" 
       name="agreement" 
       value="1" 
       id="agreement_1" 
       class="validate[minCheckbox[1]]" 
       title="custom msg">
```

None of them worked for me, instead of shown the custom message the default ones is shown:

[image]

Does any knows how to achieve this? It's driving me crazy!

Comment: I am trying to find version 2.6.21, but only find up to 2.6.4. Can you give a link?

Comment: I've had a simillar problem using jquery validate (I do not recall the version I was using) and solved it by putting the "custom message" in the attribute "title" of your inputs. Hope this helps.

Comment: @trincot here https://cdnjs.com/libraries/jQuery-Validation-Engine/2.6.2

Comment: You point to version 2.6.2. but in the question you say 2.6.21. Is that a typo?

Comment: @trincot no, it's not a typo, tbh I don't know where or when they get that version but is the one we have, I will try H. Figuereido solution now and see if that makes it to work.

Comment: @H.Figueiredo it didn't work :( I've added your solution to the OP reflecting it does not work

Comment: @trincot you were right the `2.6.21` the `1` was a type, correct version is `2.6.2` :|

Comment: Sorry, I just got home now from work. But I guess you found your solution! I'm glad!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The newer kind of configuration, based on data attributes, replaces the one that is based on the `class` attribute, so you must go all the way, and use the `data-validation-engine` attribute for that purpose:

```js
$("form").validationEngine();
```

```css
body { margin: 20px }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jQuery-Validation-Engine/2.6.2/languages/jquery.validationEngine-en.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jQuery-Validation-Engine/2.6.2/jquery.validationEngine.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jQuery-Validation-Engine/2.6.2/validationEngine.jquery.min.css">

<form>
    Confirm you have read and agree:<br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="agreement" value="1"
           data-validation-engine="validate[minCheckbox[1]]" 
           data-errormessage-range-underflow="Custom error msg">
    I have read and agree<br>
    <button>Submit</button>
</form>
```